# Want to filter only parent post in admin area

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, filters, wpdb

[image]

I want a filter like this in my custom post "books". This filter should only bring up the parent post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my previous answer add following code. It should work fine

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-books', 'add_filter_link' );
function add_filter_link( array $views ) {
    $url = add_query_arg( array('bfilter'=>'parents','post_parent'=>0,'post_type'=>'books'), 'edit.php' );
    $views[ 'post_parent' ] = sprintf(
        '<a href="%1$s"%2$s>%3$s</a>',
        esc_url( $url ),
        ( is_filter_active() ) ? ' class="current" aria-current="page"' : '',
        'Post Parents'
    );
    return $views;
}

function is_filter_active() {
    return (filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'bfilter' ) ==='parents');
}
```

if you already not used bellow code then add that too

```
function make_post_parent_public_qv() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' )
        $GLOBALS['wp']->add_query_var( 'post_parent' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'make_post_parent_public_qv' );
```

Comment: I add this code in restrict_manage_posts hook but I got nothing.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate the full code. I'm very new at this. It would be a great help to me. Please

Comment: you don't need to add this within anything. Just use this code alone.

Comment: O my god.. You are GREAT. Thanks Thanks Thanks. Please suggest me where can I learn more about this kind of stuff. And one more thing, can I filter child posts the same way.

Comment: Just explore wordpress codex a bit. hooker.io is another great place

Comment: Why it's show Books(0). is it possible to show the actual number of parent post in the parenthesis?

Comment: It's just place holder. Possible to remove. Updating the code